# How to find segment with beginning and ending string?

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to find all segment that beginning is a given string and ending is another given string.

For example, I have string to find:

```
Henry is a good student. And friends of Henry are also good students.
```

And I want to find all segment that begin with `Henry` and ends with `student`. That means, with above example, we find 2 segments:

**Henry is a good student**. And friends of **Henry are also good student** s.

Not:

**Henry is a good student. And friends of Henry are also good student** s.

All programming languages are OK with me. I just need regex.

EDIT: I'm very new in regular expression, and I tried a whole week to find but it didn't work. Some stupid case I tried:

```
/Henry.*student/

/Henry((?!student)*)student/

/Henry[^s]*student/
```

Comment: You just need to put your attempt.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in regular expression, so I don't know how to do that... So sorry if I make you disappointed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lazy modifier:

```
/Henry.*?student/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?36d1r

Comment: I'm not sure. But sometimes it works, sometimes it match whole string like: **Henry is a good student. And friends of Henry are also good student** s.

Comment: Please explain me, what does question mask (?) mean in your regex?

Comment: @funny337 - It's a *lazy modifier*. It tells the regex engine to only match as few characters as possible.

Comment: @funny337 - What language are you trying this in?

Comment: Note that this solution will match across sentences, in cases such as `Henry is a boy. He is a good student.`

Comment: @nhahtdh - The OP never said not to match across sentences.

Comment: @JosephSilber: I don't say this solution is wrong. Just a case that might be interesting.

Comment: Here is a reference for language compatibility: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html tl;dr: The lazy quantifier is available for everything but Oracle DB.

Comment: Ah, OK. It works... I tried **/Henry.*student/** but it does not, you know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
m/Henry.*?student/g
```

Here ? makes * quantifier non-greedy.

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text="Henry is a good student. And friends of Henry are also good students.";
my @matches = $text=~ m/(Henry.*?student)/g;
print Dumper \@matches;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Henry is a good student',
          'Henry are also good student'
        ];
```

Answer (score -2):

This shoud do it:

```
/Henry.*student/
```